# Akka-stream: onComplete called before mapAsync has finished to process data

Tags: scala, akka, future, akka-stream

I am presently working on a simple batch which uses AKKA stream 1.0 to process data.
All is running smoothly if i avoid using mapAsync method on flow step.

When on complete is called, the result file is finalized and the agent system is shutdown through a Reaper actor (see Reaper pattern):

```
val file = new File(inputFile)
val run: Future[Int] = source(file)
 .via(parse)
 .via(enrich)
 .via(writeEnriched)
 .runWith(printProgress)
run.onComplete { result: Try[Int] =>
 context.system.log.info(s"Nb elements processed: ${result.get}")
 writerActorRef ! FinalizeResults()
}
```

One of the step i want to accelerate is the part which enrich data. Sometimes, data can't be enriched and should be ignored for next step.

```
def enrich(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) : Flow[Data, EnrichedData, Unit]
= Flow[Data].map(enriched.enrich(_)).collect {
 case Some(enrichedData) => enrichedData
}
```

All this code is running well and i have no lost elements when onComplete() is called.

```
Input: 45639
Nb elements processed: 45639
```

When i try to accelerate thing using mapAync and Future instead of map for enrichment step, the onComplete is called before all elements have been processed.

```
def enrich(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) : Flow[Data, EnrichedData, Unit]
   = Flow[Data].mapAsyncUnordered(8)(data => Future(enricher.enrich(data))).collect {
     case Some(enrichedData) => enrichedData
   }
```

I missed some elements at the end and never the same number
All this code is running well and i have no lost elements when onComplete() is called.

```
Input: 45639
Nb elements processed: 45628
```

I cant find a way to find that everything have been processed...
Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: do you also lose elements with mapAsync?

Comment: IIRC a failing future would collapse the stream, so it would not end with a Success but a Failure

Comment: i am not loosing elements from mapAsync (controlled with a counter).

Comment: How and where are you maintaining that counter?

Comment: I have done a dummy singleton class using AtomicInteger which is increment in the enricher. I can see that enricher is called 45639 (the number of elements). The element lost are after the enricher on the write process which is using an actor which write result on a file. It receives only ~= 45628 and onComplete is called. I am suspecting mapAsyncUnordered+Future because when i use map when calling enricher, the writer receive all elements and onComplete is called at the end to finalize the result file.

Comment: how do printProgress look like? couldn't you count the elements with a fold?

Comment: i am trying to do extract my code to a simple test and i am not able to reproduce it ...

Comment: Finally i Found the issue. My issue was not on akka stream but on a limit checker which was not thread safe.... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i Found the issue. My issue was not on akka stream but on a limit checker which was not thread safe.... Thanks for your help 
For those interested, i have upload some code on github: https://github.com/PixelDuck/akka-stream-test